# Java 9u181 javac: module directory not found

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to compile a simple module, however, I keep getting this:

```
#  javac -d mods/io.adenix.greet src/io.adenix.greet/module-info.java src/io.adenix.greet/io/adenix/greet/Main.java 
   $  mods/io.adenix.greet not found
```

I am using an Oracle Java 9u181 docker image that I put together for trying out Java 9, [adenix/java:9u181](https://hub.docker.com/r/adenix/java).

### Project Structure

```
.
├── mods
│   └── io.adenix.greet
└── src
    └── io.adenix.greet
        ├── io
        │   └── adenix
        │       └── greet
        │           └── Main.java
        └── module-info.java
```

### module-info.java

```
module io.adenix.greet { }
```

### Main.java

```
package io.adenix.greet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

---

### Update 1

Here is my Dockerfile outlining the steps I took to install Java 9u181

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN \
  apt update && \
  apt install -y curl && \
  curl -jkL -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9+181/jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -o jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
  apt remove -y curl && \
  apt clean && \
  apt -y autoremove && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  tar xvzf jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
  rm -rf jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk-9/bin/java 100 && \
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac java /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac 100 && \
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jshell jshell /opt/jdk-9/bin/jshell 100

CMD ["jshell"]

# If you're reading this and have any feedback on how this image could be
# improved, please open an issue or a pull request so we can discuss it!
#
# https://github.com/adenix/docker-java/issues
```

Comment: I successfully compiled your classes. Are you running `javac` from the right directory? It should be the parent directory of `mods` and `src`

Comment: Yeah, I'm running `javac` from the parent directory.

Comment: Would you mind running the command with my docker image to help me rule out a bad install. I'm not in a spot where I'm ready to install 9 on my mac. `docker run --rm -ti -v "$PWD":/java -w /java adenix/java:9u181 javac -d mods/io.adenix.greet src/main/io.adenix.greet/module-info.java src/main/io.adenix.greet/io/adenix/greet/Main.java`?

Comment: `src/main/io.adenix.greet/module-info.java` --> I don't see directory named `main`? At this time, you can download official JDK 9 from Oracle's homepage, no need JDK 9 inside Docker.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question with a simpler structure and didn't update my command. Ill update it now

Comment: `docker run --rm -ti -v "$PWD":/java -w /java adenix/java:9u181 javac -d mods/io.adenix.greet src/io.adenix.greet/module-info.java src/io.adenix.greet/io/adenix/greet/Main.java`

Comment: I know I can download the official Java 9 from Oracle. I'm not in a place where I feel comfortable doing so on my main machine until I've figured out my migration strategies.

Comment: Voting to close as Off-Topic. *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: My question was a valid error using java 9. Just because you don't like that the answer was a bad install of java 9 doesn't mean it should be closed.

Comment: **I accidentally typed java instead of javac** is a mere example of a typographical error and nothing else and that's what the question has been flagged with. Anyway, I have just flagged it, moderators can still deny if they find it irrelevant. Neither am I downvoting nor willing to get into a further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLVED IT!

It was a simple typo in my Dockerfile.. I accidentally typed `java` instead of `javac` in my second `update-alternatives` command

#### Original

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac java /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac 100
```

#### Fixed

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk-9/bin/javac 100
```

Comment: Seems Off-topic?? *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: Not that much did I think over it. There is a question mark `?` placed in the comment. My opinion has been expressed. *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error.*** and *this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.* ....And this is the text from a flag that..https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts....and I had to flag the comment by you as well for using rude words.